# Need an SQL Query for the below requirement

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have a table containing 5000 rows of students and 6 subjects in columns including student id and student name.
Each student got a grade for each subject.Grades contain A1, A2, B1, B2 n up to E. I want to get the list of students who got A1 or A2 at least in 4 subjects out of six subjects.
And I need an SQL query to get the list of such students
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expect result?
Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Hint: Adding the result of 6 `CASE` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select * from (select [Student Id], [Student Name], (case when s1 in('A1','A2') then 1 else 0 end + 
case when s2 in('A1','A2') then 1 else 0 end +
case when s3 in('A1','A2') then 1 else 0 end +
case when s4 in('A1','A2') then 1 else 0 end +
case when s5 in('A1','A2') then 1 else 0 end +
case when s6 in('A1','A2') then 1 else 0 end ) as [A1A2 Subjects]
```

FROM [StudentMarks]
    ) A
    where [A1A2 Subjects] >=4

Hope it helps.